Fluter web compile error SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'localhost' (OS Error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known, errno = 8)
tenking@KEEs-MacBook-Pro vendfun_fnb % flutter doctor -v                                                
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.6, on macOS 14.3.1 23D60 darwin-arm64, locale en-MY)
    • Flutter version 3.19.6 on channel stable at /Users/tenking/Developer/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 54e66469a9 (4 months ago), 2024-04-17 13:08:03 -0700
    • Engine revision c4cd48e186
    • Dart version 3.3.4
    • DevTools version 2.31.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/tenking/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/tenking/Library/Android/sdk
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /Users/tenking/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11572160)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15F31d
    • CocoaPods version 1.15.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11572160)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.92.2)
    • VS Code at /Users/tenking/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.94.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Tenking (mobile) • 00008101-001E046C2110001E • ios            • iOS 17.5.1 21F90
    • macOS (desktop)  • macos                     • darwin-arm64   • macOS 14.3.1 23D60 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)     • chrome                    • web-javascript • Google Chrome 127.0.6533.120
    ! Error: Browsing on the local area network for Tay Lang iPhone. Ensure the device is unlocked and attached with a cable or associated
      with the same local area network as this Mac.
      The device must be opted into Developer Mode to connect wirelessly. (code -27)

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
tenking@KEEs-MacBook-Pro vendfun_fnb % 

Previously, I was able to run the app in a web browser, but today, for some reason, it no longer works, even after creating a new Flutter application. I hope someone can help me resolve this issue. Tried flutter run -d chrome --release also get the same error.

[  +19 ms] Failed to establish connection with the application instance in Chrome.
This can happen if the websocket connection used by the web tooling is unable to correctly establish a connection, for example
due to a  firewall.
"But my firewall was disabled now."
